# OrmLite and Java Generics

Tags: java, database, generics, orm, ormlite

I am working with OrmLite for java, and I have a problem with generics. All the classes that I use for database control are almost the same, the only thing that changes are the class types. I wanted to use java generics to do that, but I need the generic (E.class) function to work, how can I do it?

I tried using generics like:

```
public void Database<E> {
    public Database() {
        dao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, E.class);
    }
}
```

but it wont accept the E.class. What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the `Class<E>` in the constructor:

```
public Database(Class<E> clazz) {
    dao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, clazz);
}
```

Otherwise there's no way to have the `Class` that represents the generic parameter at compile-time, because the compiler is not aware of that actual type.

More info:

- [Type erasure in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)